# Complexification of maximal compact subgroup for complex semisimple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a **complex** semisimple Lie group and $H$ be a maximal compact subgroup.

> Prove that $H^{\mathbb C} = G$

This is what I've thought about :
I want to do it at the level of Lie algebra. Let $h = Lie(H)$ and $g = Lie(G)$. Let the Cartan decomposition of $g$ be $g = h+ m$. I somehow want to show that $h + ih$ is a Cartan decomposition. Then $h \otimes \mathbb C = g$ and we are done.

I'd appreciate any help available.

Comment: Showing $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus i\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan decomposition is the same thing as showing $\mathfrak{h}$ is a maximal compact subalgebra and that $[\mathfrak{h}, i\mathfrak{h}]\subset i\mathfrak{h}$, $[i\mathfrak{h},i\mathfrak{h}]\subset \mathfrak{h}$

Comment: How can I show these conditions? The Lie bracket is only $\mathbb R$ bilinear right?

Comment: No it is complex bilinear for a complex Lie algebra. We can view a complex Lie algebra as a real one but that doesn't change what the bracket does.